Are there any polls on the opinion about Hamas in the broader Arab or Muslim world?
There numerous polls about Hamas conducted by Palestinian pollsters, but at least some of these were recently contested by the IDF.
I'm curious: are there [any] polls about about Hamas in the broader Arab or Muslim world, and in particular are there some pollsters that polled both before & after Oct 7 on opinions about Hamas (in such a broader geographical area)?

According to the Washington Institute, Hamas has seen a boost in popularity among several Arab countries.

In Saudi Arabia "very positive" view of Hamas went from 2% to 18% from August 2023 to Nov/Dec 2023. And "somewhat positive" from 8% to 22% in the same country & period. Overall "There has been a thirty point shift in positive attitudes towards Hamas, from just 10% in August to 40% in November/December." Also:


Nor do most [in Saudi Arabia] believe that Hamas’s attack on October 7 targeted Israeli civilians—the overwhelming majority of Saudis (95%) responded that Hamas did not actually kill civilians when asked about whether they believed the Hamas killing of civilians was against Islam.


They don't give exact change for some other countries (but they do give the Dec/Nov 2023 numbers) and say that in "countries like Lebanon, Jordan, and Egypt [...] Hamas has a majority and in several cases unprecedented level of approval since 2014". (A more detailed answer on change in other countries would be appreciated.)

I found their Egypt page/article which was published a bit later, probably from the same poll though. The boost there was from 4% "very positive" in Nov 2020 [last time they asked there] to 41% "very positive" in Nov/Dec 2023. For "somewhat positive" it went from 19% to 34% in same period.


The Institute doesn't seem to disclose the precise firm they contracted for the poll but says it's an "independent regional commercial survey firm".

It would be more trustworthy if more details about the polling (who, how, how many) was known.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: other than saying there were 1,000 respondents in each country [apparently], not much else is disclosed. But the Institute is somewhat close to AIPAC if Wikipedia is to be believed, although perhaps less partisan. So, boosting/faking Hamas' standing doesn't seem like it would help them.

Note that it's kind of difficult to know what kind of sentiment this is capturing, since the Israel invasion of the Gaza Strip had been ongoing for about a month or two by the time of polling. So it's hard to say whether it shows that approval of Hamas's attacks was the driving factor (after all, they primarily differed only in scale from Hamas's previous actions), or to what extent it might be due to Hamas benefiting from an "enemy of my enemy" effect, where as Israel becomes less popular, anyone who opposes Israel is assumed to be doing something right.

The bit where a majority of Saudi Arabians suggested that Hamas did not actually attack civilians does lend itself to that latter, low-information interpretation, where respondents do not necessarily know precisely what Hamas did, but do know what Israel did.

The "overwhelming majority of Saudis (95%) responded that Hamas did not actually kill civilians" bit, I would say, indicates a high-misinformation situation, rather than a low-information situation.
